# Should Expats.se have city tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I created a [question regarding Addis Ababa](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/10379/what-are-the-most-practical-ways-i-can-get-a-car-for-6-months-in-addis-ababa), and requested a tag for the city to be added. It is currently the only question with that tag. However, after browsing the site, it seems that there are no city tags, not even for larger cities.

Should the site have tags for specific cities? Can it contribute anything to a question? If the agreement is that it can't, I'd be happy to add a delete request for the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a minor point: there's no such thing as a delete request for a tag. If a tag is removed from all its questions it will be deleted by a regular admin script.

On the real question: I can't see many situation where a city tag contributes much. There could be some, and in those cases they're appropriate, but unless (to take your question as an example) buying and selling cars is different in Addis Ababa to the rest of Ethiopia, a country tag would seem to be more accurate.

It's maybe also worth commenting that in general expats move to the big cities, so capital cities in particular might have less need for specific tags than others; and others might be better grouped under some kind of small-town tag.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I agree, and I've removed the tag from the question.